# PostgreSQL: fill records using fields from JSONB with jsonb_to_record()

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a function returning `jsonb`

```sql
SELECT get_my_records( 'some', 'args' );
```

| get_my_records |
| --- |
| { "a": 1, "b": 3.14 } |
| { "a": 2, "b": 2.71 } |
| ... |

and trying to use `jsonb_to_record()` to convert the records to

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.14 |
| 2 | 2.71 |
| ... | ... |

Tried

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM jsonb_to_record( val ) as x( a int, b double precision ) 
FROM get_my_records( 'some', 'arg' ) AS val;`
```

and a few variations but without success. How does one go about it?

(probably lacking proper terminology to get meaningful results from the web search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt was mostly correct, but you added multiple [`FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) lists for some reason, which isn't allowed. You can get away with a single `FROM` item if you use [`->>` accessors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) instead: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8S3ktByj)

```sql
select (j->>'a')::int as a, 
       (j->>'b')::double precision as b 
from get_my_records( 'some', 'args' ) as jdata(j);
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.14 |
| 2 | 2.71 |

You can't have multiple `from` lists in a single query - you'd have to split that into [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)s/[subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-SUBQUERIES)

```
SELECT * 
FROM jsonb_to_record( val ) as x( a int, b double precision ) 
FROM get_my_records( 'some', 'arg' ) AS val;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
> LINE 4: FROM get_my_records( 'some', 'arg' ) AS val;
>         ^
> ```

Or, you can just extend your `from` list by [joining the sources](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN):

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM get_my_records( 'some', 'arg' ) AS val 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_record(val) as x(a int,b double precision) ON TRUE;
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.14 |
| 2 | 2.71 |

You can use a comma `,` to join implicitly, since [`lateral`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) is implied by dependence between these set-returning functions posing as sources, and `on true` just lets them join freely.

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM get_my_records( 'some', 'arg' ) AS val,
     jsonb_to_record( val ) as x( a int, b double precision );
```

Comment: the SQL is not my "native tongue" (clearly need to do much more reading) and Postgres was recently added into our product's ecosystem; thanks for the answer and links

Answer (score 1):

Here how to do it using [`jsonb_to_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) :

```
SELECT rec.*
FROM get_my_records( 'some', 'arg' ) AS val,
     jsonb_to_record(val) as rec(a int, b numeric );
```

Or simply using the operator `->>` :

```
SELECT val->>'a' a , val->>'b' b
FROM get_my_records( 'some', 'arg' ) AS val
```

Comment: Both variants return the wrong type